# What non-structural coverage criteria are there?

Tags: metrics, coverage

There are huge amounts of structural coverage criteria (see e.g. [ISTQB-Standard](http://www.german-testing-board.info/fileadmin/gtb_repository/downloads/pdf/glossar/CT_Glossar_EN_DE_V23.pdf) or [ISO26262-Standard](http://www.verifysoft.com/en_ISO_26262_Road_Vehicules_Functional_Safety.html)), ranging from control-flow to data-flow coverage, applied to source code or to specifications.

So which coverage criteria are NOT structural?

---

Details: I can think of some non-structural coverage criteria, but have no idea whether there are more, and do not have a citable reference that covers non-structural coverage criteria.

Exemplary non-structural coverage criteria:

1. Coverage of requirements
2. Coverage of input values
3. Coverage of GUI elements

Comment: Anything environmental.  For example, coverage of platforms or coverage of locales.

Comment: Who is defining structural vs non structural? Is there some industry definition or some specification that gives a definition? Maybe some more context would be helpful here

Comment: It is part of the question to get a citable reference that covers non-structural and structural coverage criteria. Structural coverage criteria are mentioned in many standards, I've added some to the question. I hope it is clear from my question that by non-structural coverage criteria, I mean coverage criteria that are NOT structural.

Comment: it says: Coverage measures based on the internal structure of the component or system.

Answer (score 3):

There are the following types of test coverage criteria:

> - structural criteria
> - data criteria
> - fault-model criteria
> - requirements-based criteria
> - criteria based on explicit test case specifications
> - criteria based on statistical methods for random test data generation
> - criteria based on mutation-analysis

**All criteria except the first one are non-structural.**

---

Information sources:

1. [Practical Model-Based Testing: A Tools Approach](https://books.google.com/books?id=8hAGtY4-oOoC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA109#v=onepage&q&f=false) book, page 109;
2. [Coverage Criteria for Testing DMM Specifications](http://is.uni-paderborn.de/uploads/tx_sibibtex/Coverage_Criteria_for_Testing_DMM_Specifications.pdf) thesis, page 12;
3. [A Taxonomy of Model-Based Testing for Embedded Systems from Multiple Industry Domains](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Justyna_Zander/publication/235641058_A_Taxonomy_of_Model-Based_Testing_for_Embedded_Systems_from_Multiple_Industry_Domains/links/09e4151236657dc884000000.pdf) article, page 9;
4. [Model-Based Testing](https://books.google.com/books?id=nxe6BQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA314&pg=PA314#v=onepage&q&f=false) article;
5. [Model-Based Testing](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2012/course/DIT848/files/06-Selecting-Tests.pdf) lecture, page 2.

Comment: Thanks for the solid answer with references (+1). Is the list you gave from some article/book? Many articles oppose mutation-analysis/fault-models/ranndom testing to coverage criteria, so I wouldn't consider those as being coverage criteria. What kind of criteria based on explicit test case specification are there? Covering a set of exploratory testing tours?

Comment: Okay, I found most of the items you listed in Uttings book. They are, however, test selection criteria, not necessarily COVERAGE criteria.

Comment: The coverage criteria on meta models (see DMM paper) are either structural coverage criteria or input coverage criteria, applied to specifications.

Comment: So filtering the list of test selection criteria from your cited articles/books to test coverage criteria results in requirements coverage and input coverage. I think covering GUI elements in testing through the GUI is also a relevant coverage criterion, and not part of the list. So I still wonder whether there are more.

Comment: I still find your answer valuable, with very good references...

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I was torn between you and Alexei in giving the award. Even though your answer contains really good references, I gave the award to Alexei because he mentioned a new coverage criterion I wasn't thinking of before.

Answer (score 1):

Coverage of state transitions
Coverage of environment combinations

It says, that structural is everything which is based un underlying code or alike.

But I don't really see any practical use of this division.

Comment: Coverage of environment combinations is quite interesting (+1). Do you know of an article/book that describes this?